# Quicksort algorithm issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, sorting, quicksort

Having a problem with my quicksort algorithm. The code compiles without any errors, but when I try to run the program the only output I get is "The random numbers are: " and then acts like it wants input from the user, and then I have to kill the program. Now when I remove the call for my quicksort function in my main program, the program prints out the numbers, but doesn't work with the call for quicksort function. I'm not sure if the parameters I'm using are the issue or if it's the function itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

void quicksort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
  int l = left;
  int r = right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  while (l <= r) {
    while (arr[l] < pivot)
      l++;
    while (arr[l] > pivot)
      r--;
    if (l <= r) {
      tmp = arr[l];
      arr[l] = arr[r];
      arr[r] = tmp;
      l++;
      r--;
    }
  }

  if (left < r)
    quicksort(arr, left, r);
  if (l < right)
    quicksort(arr, r, right);

}

int main() {
  int n = 20;
  int testlist[n];

 for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
   testlist[i] = rand()%100;
 }

 cout << "The random numbers are: " << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << testlist[i] << " ";


 quicksort(testlist, 0, n - 1);

 cout << " " << endl;

 cout << "The sorted numbers are: " << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   cout << testlist[i] << " ";
 }

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: One suggestion: plain `l` (the letter L in lowercase) looks a lot like `1` which is confusing when reading code.

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinite loop in your `quicksort` function. As this function never returns, nothing after the "The random numbers are:" line is printed, as the `quicksort` call never returns. The random numbers themselves may or may not print (and do print on my system) as the system is not guaranteed to flush the output buffer to the screen immediately. (They probably would be printed if you wrote a `std::endl` to `cout` after the for loop that prints the numbers.)

I suspect this is the problem:

```
while (arr[l] > pivot)
    r--;
```

That statement `while (arr[l] > pivot)` should probably actually be `while (arr[r] > pivot)`.

Comment: David sorry, this was my wrong edit, delete your edit! Also, I am afraid this won't solve the problem and the code will crash!

Comment: I've removed my edit to match OP's current/original code. As for the crash, yes, the infinite loop wasn't the only bug in that function. Now would be a good time for OP to learn to use a debugger and step through it to see what is happening... Or just look for similar copy-paste mistakes where they've gotten variables mixed up. ;-)

Comment: Thank you David! :) Let me apologize for the confusion. :/

Answer (score 1):

This happens because something goes wrong inside `quicksort()` and you print the numbers **without an `std::endl`**!

You see, without the `std::endl`, the numbers are written in the output buffer, but they are not flushed. They will, eventually, without the `std::endl`, but that your code doesn't make it to that time.

Pro tip: **Always use `std::endl` when you debug your code**!

---

I won't debug your `quicksort()`, since you should do that, in order to *practice*! If you need a reference, you can always use my baby example: [Quicksort (C++)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/quicksort-c/), which is written in a [c](/questions/tagged/c)-like way, so that people from both [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) can easily follow! :)

---

Hunch: You use recursion, your program doesn't terminate...*Infinite loop* may be the cause... ;)

---

BTW, if I were you and didn't have any important reason to use:

```
#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__ < 1
```

I would discard that (along with the accompanied `#endif`).

Comment: I see his bug, it's just a regular, run-of-the-mill infinite loop

Comment: I tried so hard **not to tell his bug so he can practice**. Fortunately the other answer doesn't solve the issue, and I hope that he will debug seeing your code Mr. Psyduck. :)